# Replace one Library components by second library components in order to completely remove first library assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an windows application in .NET which uses two Libraries (naming LB1 and LB2). Both of these libraries are third party libraries. 
Now my client wants me to replace LB1 components by LB2 components in order to completely remove LB1 assemblies. (May be for cost cutting)

I need to check that whether the controls/methods/other functionality that was achieved with LB1 can be achieved with LB2 or not.

How can i do this?

1. Manually (I tried but it took me long to identify only a few
   controls)
2. By any tool.

Also if anyhow I could figure out that LB1.Component1 can be replaced with LB2.Component2, then how can I change the whole code?

1. Manually (It would take long time to replace each and every control individually)
2. By any tool or script

Hope my question(s) is clear, if not then please leave a comment, i would try to elaborate more.

**Edit** : It has been confirmed by client that for each control in LB1 there is a mirror copy in LB2 but dont know the exact mapping (names). This is what I have to identify. If I have to do it manually then what all things i need to take care of?

**Edit 2** : I used reflection and got to know that both of my assesblies has a class (named NCombo and Combo) which looks similar by name. Both have long descriptions. Can I anyhow know that these classes are identical?
I mean, if there was some functionality with object of NCombo then can i achieve the same functionality with object of Combo. Objects have been used at several places therefore to check for each functionality by running the app would be very difficult.
Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compare both and make sure LB2 provides the same functionalities as LB1. This is an analysis step up front, and yes, it takes time, but it will also help you to understand what you are doing and whether it is possible. Based on this you can decide next steps.

If they offer the same functionalities, the next step could be to replace controls, probably rewrite code and spend enough time to make sure everything keeps working as expected. This is called **refactoring**. And of course this is a manual job - though you could write automated tests.

If they don't offer the same functionalities, you have to decide on what the next step would be.

Comment: Edited my question a little bit.

Comment: That doesn't change the answer. You have to refactor. No tool will do that for you. And you will need to do extensive testing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your question is clear.................

You need to do everything by manually only.

Ex:
LB1 has some cotrols but LB2 deos't has those same cotrols or events. You need to check it manaully and search for a correct control and event.

As per me there is no any tool to do so. If its available also it will not do 100%.

Comment: Edited my question alittle bit.

Comment: If you want to do it manually then you need to check the Events and Properties of controls. May some properties and events not be supported by later library.